# Drawing parallel planes given only 1-2 points?

Tags: graphics3d, plotting

Assuming I'm given an arbitrary 3D curve, what I'm trying to do is draw a plane (or a pair of parallel planes) given only one or two points to work with. Now, I know that 3 points are required to define a plane, but I've been trying to work around this by placing points arbitrarily close to my given points in order to draw the planes.

For example,[image]

[image]

This is an example of something I am trying to do. Given only two points, I was able to draw a plane that appeared perpendicular to the structure above the plane. Of course, this was simply a semicircle that had its endpoints in the XY plane, so it was very easy to do. Let's say I had something more complicated such as this function 
`ParametricPlot3D[{t, t, t^3}, {t, -2, 2}, Axes -> False, 
 Boxed -> False]`

I'd like to draw planes at the endpoints of the curve that appear to be parallel.
[image]

Edit: Just like this, except where the black lines are actual 3D planes

[image]

Comment: Your problem is mathematically ill-defined and hence cannot be solved.  For example, in your final example, why did you make the lines ("planes") both *horizontal*?  You added that arbitrary constraint.

Comment: Yes, the issue is precisely that it is mathematically ill-defined. But, what I can do is dance around this issue by, say, picking extra points in order to define a plane and then manipulate the chosen points in such a way that I can "rotate" the plane by inspection in a more elegant way than simply just randomly picking points. I'm assuming this might be able to be done using Manipulate.

Answer (score 1):

To pick two parallel planes (out of infinitely many), you can

1. Pick a random direction and
2. use this direction to construct two `InfinitePlane`s passing through
   the two points on the curve:

```
{pnt1, pnt2} = {{-2, -2, (-2)^3}, {2, 2, 2^3}};
SeedRandom[77777]
randomdir = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {2, 3}]
```

> {{0.262081, -1.50893, 0.331108}, {-0.523886, 0.100094, 0.71017}}

```
Show[ParametricPlot3D[{t, t, t^3}, {t, -2, 2}], 
 Graphics3D[{{Green, Sphere[{pnt1, pnt2}, .3], 
    Opacity[.5], Red, EdgeForm[], InfinitePlane[pnt1, randomdir], 
    Blue, InfinitePlane[pnt2, randomdir]}}], PlotRange -> All, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral", Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}]
```

[image]

To pick a random plane passing through the two points, you can use `InfinitePlane` by appending a random third point to the two points:

```
Show[ParametricPlot3D[{t, t, t^3}, {t, -2, 2}], 
 Graphics3D[{{Green, Sphere[{pnt1, pnt2}, .3], Opacity[.5], Red, 
    EdgeForm[], InfinitePlane[{pnt1, pnt2, randomdir[[1]]}]}}], 
 PlotRange -> All, Lighting -> "Neutral", Axes -> False, 
 Boxed -> False, Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}]
```

[image]